# dropdownlist control asp.net C# Error is 'ASP.pract2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'dropDownList_Changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

This whole problem is about a dropdownlist in asp.net using C#. I don't quite understand the error message about asp.pract2.aspx does not contain a definition for DropDownListChanged. Everything I have searched on Youtube for a solution deals with Visual Studio. And I'm working straight from notepad++ using xampp server. I believe I got the right syntax for , but I'm not 100% sure. Because I've been correcting errors all day. I've followed my textbook instructions as best as I can at this point in my training, but now I've hit a wall. I don't know what to do next. I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this and point me in the right direction. Here is the short code.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
  <script runat="server">
  void dropDownList1_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  int i = ((DropDownList) sender).SelectedIndex;
  string str = "";
  switch (i)
  {
  case 0: 
  str = "You selected Sunday"; break;
  case 1: 
  str = "You selected Monday"; break;
  case 2: 
  str = "You selected Tuesday"; break;
  case 3: 
  str = "You selected Wednesday"; break;
  case 4: 
  str = "You selected Thursday"; break;
  case 5: 
  str = "You selected Friday"; break;
  case 6: 
  str = "You selected Saturday"; break;
  default: 
  str = "Please select a day"; break;
  }
  label1.Text = str + ": " + ((DropDownList) sender).SelectedItem.Value;
  }
  </script>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:DropDownList id="dropDownList1" runat="server" accesskey="1"    AutoPostBack="True"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList_Changed"/> 
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Sun"/>Sun</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Mon"/>Mon</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Tue"/>Tue</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Wed"/>Wed</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Thu"/>Thu</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Fri"/>Fri</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Sat"/>Sat</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
 <br><br>'This is where I'm going to put a button control
 <p><asp:Label id="label1" Runat="server"/></p>        
 </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: Yeah, your right. ConnorsFan below pointed that out to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few problems in the declaration of your DropDownList. You can try with the following markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList1_Changed" AccessKey="1" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Sun">Sun</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Mon">Mon</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Tue">Tue</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Wed">Wed</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Thu">Thu</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Fri">Fri</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Sat">Sat</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My corrections:

1. The name of the event handler is now `dropDownList1_Changed` (as declared in the script block) instead of `dropDownList_Changed`
2. Your elements are declared with a self-closing tag (e.g. `<asp:ListItem ... />` and also have a closing tag (e.g. `</asp:ListItem>`). You cannot have both. This is true for the declaration of the DropDownList itself, as well as for the ListItems. I kept the closing tags and removed the self-closing part of the opening tags.

Comment: I fixed those closing tags as you suggested and reloaded the page. Now I get a Literal content ('Sun</asp:ListItem>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'.. I'm thrown by this because that is my List Item.It's the purpose of the program. Anybody knows what that means, please?

Comment: You can try copy/pasting my code in your file. I think you forgot a self-closing tag (maybe after `Value="Sun"`).

Comment: Thank you guys so much. Everything works as expected.